# ElasticSearch get top result in combination bucket aggregator

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index where each document is a line from a file with a load of metadata attached such as project and author etc.

I have written an Elastic Search query that can aggregate the files together but as we have versions of the file through time I have to also aggregate by time and I can't workout how to add in a top_hits aggregator that will give me the file/path name for the newest version. Any ideas?

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "swan heights"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "files_bucket": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "path": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "path"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "date_histogram": {
                                "field": "timestamp",
                                "calendar_interval": "1s",
                                "format": "iso8601"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 1
}
```

currently returns:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 71,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.013937337,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "lines",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "asdfefwfad",
                "_score": 0.013937337,
                "_source": {
                    "projectId": 680,
                    "projectName": "swan heights",
                    ...
                    
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "files_bucket": {
            "after_key": {
                "path": "ducks.txt",
                "timestamp": "2021-02-26T12:08:20.000Z"
            },
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": {
                        "path": "swans.txt",
                        "timestamp": "2021-02-25T12:10:43.000Z"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 17
                },
                {
                    "key": {
                        "path": "ducks.txt",
                        "timestamp": "2021-02-25T12:13:43.000Z"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 27
                },
                {
                    "key": {
                        "path": "ducks.txt",
                        "timestamp": "2021-02-26T12:08:20.000Z"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 27
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

where I only want the newest version of each file and not both versions of ducks.txt

Answer (score 0):

Composite aggs [can accept sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_sub_aggregations). So try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "swan heights"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "files_bucket": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "path": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "path"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "timestamp": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "calendar_interval": "1s",
                "format": "iso8601"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_agg": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```